# Codeigniter Update Batch Query Issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to deduct quantity directly by column but it adding single quotes in query.

Can any body know solution for it ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qnty_hold] => qnty_hold + 1
            [qnty] => qnty - 1
            [sku] => LN_STEEL_N3_BLK_M
        )

)

//Query Set
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
$this->db->update_batch('table', $batchUpdateProductQtyData, 'sku');

//Query output
UPDATE table SET qnty_hold = CASE WHEN sku = 'LN_STEEL_N3_BLK_M' THEN 'qnty_hold + 1' ELSE qnty_hold END, qnty = CASE WHEN sku = 'LN_STEEL_N3_BLK_M' THEN 'qnty - 1' ELSE qnty END WHERE sku IN ('LN_STEEL_N3_BLK_M')
```

Answer (score 0):

By Default codeigniter will try to protect your queries. when using a select statement you override this like so

```
$this->db->select("somefield",$value,FALSE);
```

try putting false at the end of your update_batch, it's worth a try.